# Fix ui-router on certain state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've a SPA angular app routed by ui-router.

It have about 50 different ui-router states.

It is hosted in different modes: a "flex" mode and "fixed" mode.

In "flex" mode ui router behave normally, using location hash to manage location.

But in "fixed" mode ui router state is encoded in location URI, which means two things:

1) State must be forced on load

2) Other states should be blocked, location hash must be blocked too.

Question is how to block ui router for certain states?

Comment: can the mode be changed without reloading the page? If not, then you don't define those certain states when in fixed mode.

Comment: @Prasad seems like it is forced to reload always, because location is being changed anyway, so yes: i can just skip definition of the states which are blocked. But what if it possible to block state programmatically? Just want explore additional options and choose best.